# Is ${f'_n(z)}$ converge uniformly on $D$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Given  $D=\{z\in C:|z|<1\}$ and let $f_n:D\to C$ be defined by $f_n(z)=\frac{z^n}{n}$ for $n=1,2,...$

Is  ${f'_n(z)}$ converge uniformly on $D$?

My attempts :$$f_n(z) := \frac{1}{n} \cdot z^n$$

where $z \in D:=B(0,1):= \{z \in \mathbb{C}; |z|<1\}$. Then

$$|f_n(z)| \leq \frac{1}{n} \to 0 \quad (n \to \infty)$$

i.e. $f_n \to 0$ uniformly in $D$.

But im confused in  ${f'_n(z)}$ ?

any hints/solution will be appreciated

thanks u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, $f_n'(z) \to 0$ for each $z \in D$. If $f_n' \to 0$ uniformly then there exists $m$ such that  $|f_n'(z)| <\frac 1 {2e}$ for all $n \geq m$ for all $z \in D$. Put $z=1-\frac 1 n$. We get $(1-\frac 1 n)^{n-1} <\frac 1 {2e}$ for all $n \geq m$. Letting $n \to \infty$ we get $\frac 1 e \leq \frac 1 {2e}$ which is a contradiction. Hence the convergence is b=not uniform.